# InitialState of Store with 2 reducers while testing a component

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, ngrx

I am trying to test a component. It uses 2 different reducer states with Ngrx.
How can I tell in the initialState of the test which one comes from AppState and the other comes from AdminState (LazyLoaded) please?

```
describe('UploadImageComponent', () => {
  let component: UploadImageComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<UploadImageComponent>;
  const initialState = {
    selectedPage: null,         // comes from AppState
    pages: [],                  // comes from AppState
    uploadLoading: false,       // comes from AdminState (LazyLoaded)
    thumbnailIsCreating: false  // comes from AdminState (LazyLoaded)
  };

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [UploadImageComponent],
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule,
        AngularFireDatabaseModule,
        AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase)
      ],
      providers: [
        PageDbService,
        AdminService,
        PagesService,
        provideMockStore({ initialState }),
      ]
    })
      .compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(UploadImageComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

While running ng test, karma says :

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'thumbnailIsCreating' of undefined

I think selectedPage and pages are well passed, but not the two others from AdminState. Is it because AdminState is lazyLoaded? Or maybe the initialState is wrong?

Comment: If that state slice is created by a forFeature reducer in a lazy module, it simply won’t exist yet if that module hasn’t been used yet..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's most likely your `initialState` is wrong.

Download the Redux dev tools (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/redux-devtools/lmhkpmbekcpmknklioeibfkpmmfibljd?hl=en, there is also a Firefox one) and see the structure of your store using that tool. This is how you configure it (https://ngrx.io/guide/store-devtools) and then you can do npm start and should see the structure of your store.

I bet your initialState should be something like this:

```
initialState = {
  selectedPage: null,         // comes from AppState
  pages: [],
  admin: {
      uploadLoading: false,       // comes from AdminState (LazyLoaded)
      thumbnailIsCreating: false
  }             
 
}
```

Comment: I looked in dev tools and then you were partially right. selectedPage and pages were in Pages Store (which herit from AppState). Now it's working, thanks.